# How to fight your anxiety?

Tags: untagged

I would like to know how I can conquer my fears.

I'm not talking about big fear like the fear of death, etc., I just want to know how to conquer the fears we face in our daily life.

I'm going to share a little story with you:

> Yesterday, my friends and I went to a Baraath. We joined the DJ and all of my friends started dancing while I stood to the side watching. I was fearful that people would judge me, so I just stood there watching them having fun even though I wanted to dance so badly. The same thing happened today.

I really don't know what I should do. Can someone please guide me?

Comment: See some videos on fear by Prashant Tripathi on his yt channel "Acharya Prashant" it might be helpful....

Comment: Anxiety is a better word than fear. Ig you are a teenager

Comment: @Rambhakt     Yeah whatever  I'm so sick of this feeling it's holding me back from enjoying some of the most precious moments of my life

Comment: @AbhinavRaj i suggested change of word as people will be able to understand your question better. As much as it is concerned, you will learn to let go. No matter what you do people are going to judge you. Even if you just stand quietly at the corner of the room, people will judge you. Even girls will think of you as underconfident so it is not like you are saving yourself from judgement by not doing what you want. Hypothetically, if you dance like this then some may laugh at you, some will like to see you enjoying but both categories will forget about you after some moments.

Comment: You seem to have good gang of friends so it is better to enjoy with them. People will notice you even less in group. I personally always wished for such a group of friends. Girls will not think negatively of you because they like confident boys. So enjoy your life. Adulthood is tough so enjoy this period as long as it lasts.

Answer (score 2):

Read this [Source](https://www.dlshq.org/download/conquest-of-fear/)

Swami sivananda said that repeat this Mantra "Om courage and Im a fearless soul"

Also , think  yourself as a  soul  not a body.

It is written  in the book Page no :15

> The more you think of Atman , the  more courageous you will become .By constant hammering only  can you  entirely  derive  the  nail into the wall or a plank.Even so , by constant and protracted thinking on atman alone  you  can become  absolutely fearless.

Answer (score 1):

Anxiety is caused due to Vata dosha in your body. Please do Yoga and Pranayama related to Vata Dosha. Anuloma/Viloma and Om chanting really help a lot.

Also, the Ayurveda medicines Brahmi Vita and Saraswathi Rista.

You can watch the below video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UwOe-_2y7uE&list=PLwGOPXZpXPJWsmBGmaAHTl0V1MYWd0gkk&index=16

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WBRpOpgPDr8

Answer (score 1):

My Acharya says fear and thus anxiety is an echo of past lives karmas which manifest in present or upcoming lives. And fasts are one of the best ways to purify the mind and reduce the past lives imprint.

Anxiety might be closely, if not fully described by the Sanskrit word उद्विग्नता.

And Matsya Purana suggest following the vow of Surya saptami vrata which is a fast dedicated to deity Sun-god.

You can refer to Chapter 68 of the Matsya purana publishing by geeta press gorakhpur as follows -
https://archive.org/details/matsya-puran-gita-press-gorakhpur/page/n271/mode/1up

Narada inquires from Lord Shiv ji

> verse 1 - **किमुद्वेगाद्धुते** कृत्यमलक्ष्मीः केन हन्यते ।
>
> What is the way to sail through a **sudden and impactful trauma**
> (anxiety, fear, depression, etc)?

And in the whole chapter ahead Shiv ji describe the methods to perform fast for Sun to sail through anxiety and other related problems.

Comment: Interesting to know fasts can remove anxiety. Can i know your Acharya ji's name if you don't mind?

Answer (score 0):

you can try reciting the Aditya Hrdayam stotram (or just listen to it)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e0yVoUKdvIU

http://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga105/yuddha_105_frame.htm

Sage Agastya advises Rama to recites the 'Aditya Hridaya', a collection of verses in praise of the sun-god, with a view to gaining victory.

Answer (score 0):

Try listening to Narasimha Swmai's Mantras. It helps me a lot, I use this before an interview to get rid of my fear and anxiety. I'll share a youtube video link for your reference. Listen to this after taking a head bath before starting your day. The link - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ghOd7lPtskk